# How to print each word of string in unix separately and get the position

Tags: unix, awk, sed

How can i compare values of each word for a given string

Sample string

`i am over here
  i am programmer` (this line must start just after first lines i )

Requirement:
Need to check on which column(place) 1st string starts and have to ensure the second line must start from the same column(place).

Comment: Post the expected output given that sample input and explain the problem better. You haven't received other answers yet because so far the question is unclear but whatever it is you are trying to do the answer you have currently selected is the wrong approach and contains bugs that will bite you given other contents of your input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first non blank like this:

```
lead=$(head -n1 file | grep -o '^ *')
col=$(echo $lead | wc -c)
((col--))
echo "column: $col"
```

Now remove first blanks of second row and add the appropriate amount of blanks.

```
sed -i "2s/^ */$lead/" file
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
       haha
  some test
$ bash script.sh
colummn: 6
$ cat file 
       haha
       some test
```

Here script.sh contains the above lines of code.

Comment: Thank you @shellfish . my approach is like step1. Get the column no. From where the letters in first line starts by using loop within same line number Y and 'i' as XX by comparing each combination of Y*XX = '' and saves the !='' 's  XX no. . step2. Will check in next line whether XX position and XX+-1 position's value = '' or not. Is there any way to implement the same.

Comment: Try awk to solve the problem, when you're stuck or run into a problem, place another question!